# check solr facet query if it is greater than specific datetime value

Tags: solr, facet, faceted-search

I have the following in solr

```
<str name="id">2</str>
<arr name="parsed">
    <str>2011-11-01 13:40:08.0</str>
</arr>
<arr name="person">
    <str>Harsh Snehanshu | Apoorv Jain</str>
</arr>
```

now if i want to search for `jain`, simply i will use this query

```
http://192.168.1.135:8888/solr/MyCol/select/?q=*%3A*&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&facet=true&fq=person:jain
```

now the question is: **how can i search for entries that have been parsed AFTER (greater than) 2011-11-01 13:00:00 or (between 2011-11-01 12:30:00 and 2011-11-01 13:30:00)??**
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parsed field needs to be defined as a [datefield](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/schema/DateField.html).

e.g.

schema.xml -

Field type of TrieDateField should be available -

```
<fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
```

Map the prased field with the tdate field type as -

```
<field name="parsed" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

So, when indexed, the response it would appear as `<date name="parsed">2009-04-28T00:00:00Z</date>`

This would allow you to use [date filter queries](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax#Differences_From_Lucene_Query_Parser) for the datefield.

e.g. `fq=parsed:[1995-12-31T23:59:59.999Z TO 2007-03-06T00:00:00Z]`

Also for search it would be better to use `q=person:jain`.
Use filter queries for restricting the documents rather than searching.

Comment: plz excuse my limited knowledge in solr:
i have added      <field indexed="true" multiValued="true" name="parsed" omitNorms="false" stored="true" type="datefield"/>
but it gives me "Unknown fieldtype 'datefield' specified on field parsed" what is the correct syntax?? thanks

Comment: :( i am testing for 100 document (just as a test)... now after adding exactly what you told me above.. i got: <str name="">
Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 documents.
</str> <str name="Total Documents Failed">100</str>
Thanks

Comment: whats the exception during the indexing ?

Comment: i have edited the question to include the response as it is larger that the comment limit

Comment: can you check the logs of tomcat/jetty which would show you the exception.

Answer (score 0):

These query parameters should work (*not tested and not url escaped*)

```
facet.field=parsed
f.parsed.facet.range.start=2011-11-01T12:30:00Z
f.parsed.facet.range.end=2011-11-01T13:30:00Z
```

Explanation:

- `facet.field=parsed` enables faceting in the field `parsed`.
- `f.parsed.facet.range.start/end` define the lower and upper bound for that field.
- Dates should be in ISO 8601 format, but also "date math" expressions like `NOW+1YEAR` are allowed.

See the **Facet by Range** section in the [Solr documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#rangefaceting) for further details.